# Create type with values from a certain property from objects in array?

Tags: typescript

I have objects in an array. All objects have the property `code`.

```
export const languageCodeToLanguageOption = [
    { code: 'cs', displayOrder: 1, text: 'Česky' },
    { code: 'zhhans', displayOrder: 2, text: '简体中文' },
];
```

How can I create a type with all `code` values without having to repeat them as I am doing below?

```
export type LanguageCode = 'cs' | 'zhhans';
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
export const languageCodeToLanguageOption = [
    { value: 'cs', displayOrder: 1, text: 'Česky' },
    { value: 'zhhans', displayOrder: 2, text: '简体中文' },
] as const;

export type LanguageCode = typeof languageCodeToLanguageOption[number]['value'];
```